# Fetching all the paths between two nodes using SQL Server Graph 2017

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, graph-databases, sql-graph

I found many examples of fetching paths between 2 nodes in neo4j and gremlin but could not find any on SQL Server Graph 2017.
Though it uses Cypher's Match, I was thinking if it is possible to find the path using only Match?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Since SQL Server 2019 you can use [`SHORTEST_PATH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/graphs/sql-graph-shortest-path) algorithm. It doesn't allow you to list all paths though, only the *shortest one*, hence the name.

You can either create your own CLR function to do that, use `WHILE` cycle to traverse the graph step by step or download the whole graph and traverse it using `C#`.